# Google Sheets API Exceptions

Tags: java, android, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write to a google sheets document using the google sheets API. I am using the sample code that is provided in the quickstart however I am getting a null pointer exception. The error occurs at this line

`Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Update request = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values()
                .update(spreadsheetID, range, valRange);`

I believe this is happening because this line is returning a null object

`Sheets sheetsService = createSheetsService();`

Below is the code for the createSheetsService() method.

```
public static Sheets createSheetsService() throws IOException {
    try {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        // TODO: Change placeholder below to generate authentication credentials. See
        // https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample
        //
        // Authorize using one of the following scopes:
        //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
        //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
        //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
        //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("PathToProject"))
                .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));

        return new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Test App")
                .build();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Security Exception " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm fairly certain this is returning null because of the catch statement at the end. But if I try to just throw the GeneralSecurityException rather than use a try catch I get this error

`Unhandled exception: java.security.GeneralSecurityException`

I'm really at a loss here, any help is much appreciated.
This is the rest of the code from my MainActivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText nameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final String name = nameText.getText().toString();

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            write(name);

        }
    });
}


public static void write(String args) {
    try {
        String spreadsheetID = "mySpreadSheetID";
        String valueInputOption = "RAW";
        BatchUpdateValuesRequest requestBody = new BatchUpdateValuesRequest();
        List<ValueRange> data = new ArrayList<>();
        //List<List<Object>> vals = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList((Object) "hello world"));
        ValueRange valRange = new ValueRange();
        valRange.setValues(
                Arrays.asList(
                        Arrays.asList((Object) ""),
                        Arrays.asList((Object) "Row 2 Cell 1", (Object) "Row 2 Cell 2")));


        String range = "A2";
        valRange.setRange(range);

        Sheets sheetsService = createSheetsService();
        Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Update request = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values()
                .update(spreadsheetID, range, valRange);
        request.setValueInputOption(valueInputOption);
        UpdateValuesResponse response = request.execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Sheets createSheetsService() throws IOException {
   try {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        // TODO: Change placeholder below to generate authentication credentials. See
        // https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample
        //
        // Authorize using one of the following scopes:
        //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
        //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
        //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
        //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("PathToProject"))
                .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));

        return new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("TestApp")
                .build();
   } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Security Exception " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
   }
}
```

}

Comment: Well, you'll throw that error if you have a problem with your credentials. So... is the path to your credentials OK? Are the scopes you are requesting sufficient to build the service?

Comment: The path to credentials is accurate. I'm not sure if the scopes are sufficient, is there an easy way to check this?

Comment: Yes, for the tasks and services you request, consult the Google Identity Platform. It will indicate the scopes you need - several scopes may be available, and not all scopes are equivalent.

Comment: Could I just set the credential to be null? The example given in the API just has null and for my application I really don't need any sort of sign in

Comment: you can't really do anything but read published data without using OAuth to build an authenticated service.